# Android: Image as answer in array

Tags: android, eclipse, image, imageview

I am trying to add an image to be a response to an array, however I don't know how to do it. I am extremely new to this, so please bear with me (using Eclipse).

```
public String[] mAnswers = {

"Do you really have to ask me about that? It's a yes.",
"Concentrate and ask again",
"You have no life. So yes.",
"It's okay to play.",
-image here that I wish to add-

};
```

I have the image saved in my res\drawable-mdpi\gaben.png

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For this case you can take two arrays

one is string array and other is int array.Look at this

```
public String[] mAnswers = {
"Do you really have to ask me about that? It's a yes.",
"Concentrate and ask again",
"You have no life. So yes.",
"It's okay to play."
};

public String[] images = {
R.drawable.image1,
R.drawable.image2,
R.drawable.image3,
R.drawable.image4
};
```

Now you can use these two arrays for your requirement

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1: image as Bitmap**

The mAnswers variable is declared as String[], so an array of Strings.

String is not an image.

You cannot mix object types.

Your image needs to be stored somewhere else, or you need to type mAnswers differently, like Object[].

**Case 2: image as path**

Save the Bitmap's path as String into your array.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object that wraps both the information and declare an array of this object

```
public class Bean {
  public final int mImageId;
  public final String mMessage;
  public Bean(int imageId, String message) {
    mImageId = imageId;
    mMessage = message;
  }
}

   Bean[] info = { new Bean(R.drawable.image1, "my first message"), ... } ;
```